# import ... as ... appears to fail, 'module' has no attribute

Tags: python, centos

have a python web service based on webware for python. In this app, there a multiple "contexts", essentially extensions of the base app with specializations. There are five of these. The one added today is throwing an error, but the others added days ago do not.

```
import MyModule as mv

class Main():
    def __init__(self):
        self.vendorcode = mv.id
```

The code above raises the error at `"self.vendorcode = mv.id"` saying the module does not have the attribute `"id"`. The file `"MyModule.py"` that is imported contains the following:

```
# config parameters
id = 'TEST'
code = 'test_c'
name = 'test_n'
```

There is nothing else in the file.

Why would this setup work in four other sub directories, aka "contexts", but not in this last one? To put this another way, what should I be looking for? I have confirmed file permissions and file char set type, which appear to fine.

UPDATE: I changed "id" to "ident" but the error was still raised. Using the print verifies that the module file is the correct one. Using the python 2.4.3 interpreter, I see that the file is loaded. In the sample below "TRANS" is the expected return value.

```
>>> import MoluVendor as mv
>>> print mv.ident
TRANS
>>>
```

So I wrote a quick test, saved it as a file in the directly with MyModule, as follows:

```
import MyModule as mv

class MainTest:
    def __init__(self):
        self.vendorcode = mv.ident

    def showme(self):
        print self.vendorcode

if __name__ == '__main__':
    mt = MainTest()
    mt.showme()
```

That reports correctly too. So the import is working in the simple case.

What bothers me is that there are four other sets of files, including a "MyModule.py" in each, that work fine. I compared the code the code and I cannot find any differences. All of these files sets are invoked by one app running as a deamon in Apache. For that reason, having only one not work is perplexing.

Comment: You could look for another file named `MyModule.py` that is being imported instead of the one you meant to import.  Are you sure the file that has those values is the one that is imported?

Comment: try `print MyModule.__file__` - that will tell you if you got the right module. And change id to something else because its also a builtin python function.

Comment: I found the problem. See answer below. (I hope posting an answer is the correct thing to do)

Answer (score 0):

I went through the files involved and checked each for gremlins. That is, I made certain the files were ASCII, no unicode or embedded characters, and saved them using an acceptable code page spec. I reloaded the app and everything now works.

So, in the end, the problem was between the chair and the keyboard. When I modified the app files for the new "context", I neglected (apparently) to save the files in the proper format.